# Show directory path in Finder in MacOS

Tags: finder, macos, folders

How to see the directory path or navigation bar in Finder? Is there any ubuntu or windows like directory bar?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Got the solution. `View -> Show Path Bar` solves it.

Comment: This doesn't show the ful unix path though